# CoreData serious application error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

Every once in awhile, I get the following error message in my application.  This happens after my application receives back a web service response via RestKit w/ CoreData integration:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  no object at index 3 in section at index 0 with userInfo (null)
2014-07-28 12:48:26.348 Identify[43074:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no object at index 3 in section at index 0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0270e1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0248d8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreData                            0x006d7dbe -[NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:] + 398
    3   Identify                            0x0002d03e -[WTSRecordListViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] + 190
    4   Identify                            0x0002c5f6 -[WTSRecordListViewController controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:] + 646
    5   CoreData                            0x006df296 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 5238
    6   Foundation                          0x02160049 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke + 40
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x02769f04 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x026c1efb _CFXNotificationPost + 2859
    9   Foundation                          0x02099e41 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 98
    10  CoreData                            0x005e1a13 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 83
    11  CoreData                            0x00680faf -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:] + 367
    12  CoreData                            0x005dceb8 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 2152
    13  CoreData                            0x005e02fc -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 140
    14  Identify                            0x000d1ffd __61-[NSManagedObjectContext(RKAdditions) saveToPersistentStore:]_block_invoke + 125
    15  CoreData                            0x0060584f developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 95
    16  CoreData                            0x0060578c -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 140
    17  Identify                            0x000d1b83 -[NSManagedObjectContext(RKAdditions) saveToPersistentStore:] + 739
    18  Identify                            0x00048d28 __80-[WTSObjectManager getRecordsForUser:forGroup:startIndex:limit:success:failure:]_block_invoke_2 + 2456
    19  Identify                            0x0014f551 __66-[RKObjectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke244 + 97
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02f747b8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02f894d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02f77726 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 340
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0277343e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x026b45cb __CFRunLoopRun + 1963
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x026b39d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x026b37eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x0367c5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x0367c42b GSEventRun + 104
    29  UIKit                               0x0114df9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    30  Identify                            0x0000279d main + 141
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x031be701 start + 1
```

Once it gets into this state, there is no way to fix it without removing the app and adding it back on to the device.  I am using the stock boilerplate code apple defines for Core Data fetch results controllers:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"begin updates");
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            NSLog(@"inserting section");
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            NSLog(@"deleting section");
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            NSLog(@"inserting row");
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            NSLog(@"deleting row");
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            NSLog(@"update row");
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            NSLog(@"move row");
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"end updates");
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

The `configureCell` method just looks like this and is failing when I'm getting the record from the fetchedResultsController:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //if a nil cell was passed into this method, just return
    if (!cell) {
        return;
    }

    WTSRecordCell *recordCell = (WTSRecordCell *)cell;
    WTSRecord *record = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
...
}
```

The following code is where I create the fetchedResultsController.  In my application, I create two separate instances of `WTSRecordListViewController`, one with a fetch request that returns back 'records' by user and the other returns 'records' by group.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController == nil) {
        WTSUserInfo *userInfo = [WTSConfiguration sharedConfig].orgConfig.userInfo;
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = nil;
        if (self.type == RecordListTypeUser) {
            fetchRequest = [[WTSObjectManager sharedManager] fetchRequestForRecordsByUser:userInfo.username];
        } else if (self.type == RecordListTypeGroup) {
            fetchRequest = [[WTSObjectManager sharedManager] fetchRequestForRecordsByGroup:userInfo.groupId];
        }

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createDt" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
        NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" cacheName:nil];
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
        self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            DDLogWarn(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here, and if this is some sort of bug in Apple's code.  Like I said previously, this happens only once in awhile (probably when the backend core data is in some sort of very specific state, since I can never seem to recreate it after it happens).

**EDIT:**
After some additional searching around, I found the code that is causing the problem.  In the `success` block in RestKit for the web service call I am making, I iterate through some database objects setting certain values.  When I am done iterating through the values, I call `[context saveToPersistentStore]`; that call is what is causing the fetched results controller methods to be fired.  If I comment out the `saveToPersistentStore` call, I don't get the exception.

The `success` block in RestKit gets executed on the main thread.  Also, according to my printouts, the block gets executed outside of the `controllerWillChangeContent:` and `controllerDidChangeContent:` methods.

**EDIT 2:**
The following code is where I make my web service call via RestKit.  In it, I iterate through the objects returned back in the mapping array setting how the records were fetched for later orphan purging.  I also execute a fetch request on the records not returned back from the fetch request and clear out a flag (also for orphan purging).

No where in my RestKit success blocks am I checking to make sure that the objects returned in the mapping request are deleted or objects returned from a fetch request are deleted before modifying them.  Is this something I need to do?

```
[self.rkObjectManager getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:kWTSRecordsRouteName object:nil parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSArray *records = [mappingResult array];

        //we put the record ids we get back in the request in a set
        NSMutableSet *recordIds = [NSMutableSet new];

        //set in the record how this was fetched
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
        for (WTSRecord *record in records) {
            [recordIds addObject:record.recordId];
            if (!context) {
                context = record.managedObjectContext;
            }

            if (groupId) {
                record.fetchedViaGroup = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
            } else {
                record.fetchedViaUser = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
            }
        }

        //if the startIndex is 0, the user is refreshing.  We clear the 'fetchedVia*' field for any records that DID NOT come back in this request
        if (startIndex == 0) {
            NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"WTSRecord"];
            if (groupId) {
                request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recordId != nil AND fetchedViaGroup == 1 AND pendingDelete == 0"];
            } else {
                request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recordId != nil AND fetchedViaUser == 1 AND pendingDelete == 0", user];
            }

            NSArray *records = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
            for (WTSRecord *record in records) {
                if (![recordIds containsObject:record.recordId]) {
                    if (groupId) {
                        record.fetchedViaGroup = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
                    } else {
                        record.fetchedViaUser = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //save the changes to the persistent store
        [context saveToPersistentStore:nil];

        success(records);
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        failure(error);
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
    }];
```

**EDIT 3**
I found the code that is causing the problem in the above snippet:

```
//set in the record how this was fetched
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
            for (WTSRecord *record in records) {
                [recordIds addObject:record.recordId];
                if (!context) {
                    context = record.managedObjectContext;
                }

//              if (groupId) {
//                  record.fetchedViaGroup = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
//              } else {
//                  record.fetchedViaUser = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
//              }
            }
```

With the following lines commented out, I am able to make the call to `saveToPersistentStore` without issues.  What am I doing wrong here?  What is the acceptable way to modify objects that come back in a mappingResult and save the changes to the local data store?

Comment: I had faced a similar problem when I had hooked up a FRC to a tableView. The problem for me was that tableView's reloadData method was being called whilst FRC was updating my tableView. After I stubbed out the reload method. I did not get the error. So it could be that there's a conflict between the dataSource and the FRC.

Comment: The first line gives the clue to the problem

    no object at index 3 in section at index 0 with userInfo (null)

Without seeing your code I'm guessing that you have a tableview with 4 sections and in the 4th section there is a scenario where you have deleted cells and are trying to insert before the table knows what's happening

Comment: See my edits above.  I found the code that is causing the problem, but I am still unclear why it would be causing any problems.

Comment: What does the code which makes changes and saves do? Does it change objects which have been deleted? Do you protect against that / check it?

Comment: Wain, see edit 2 to my post.  I am not checking for deletes, but is this something you need to do when modifying objects returned from the mappingResult or from a fetch request?

Comment: Forgive me for questioning your logic, but could you not use a single attribute to replace your attributes `record.fetchedViaGroup` and `record.fetchedViaUser`? For example, a replacement named `fetchedViaGroupNotUser`, that if equals [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] is for Group and if equals [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] is by default User. If this is possible it may simplify your code.

Comment: Also would it be wise to check for `success` within your block before you run the code? It may be that certain fetches are not populating [mappingResult array] fast enough for your `for (WTSRecord *record in records)` loop?

Comment: I don't think I can really simplify the logic.  I'm using RestKit's fetch request block capability to delete orphaned objects.  It will clear out any records where `fetchedViaUser` and `fetchedViaGroup` are both `NO`.  I'm not really sure where you are saying I should check for `success`?  The code I'm writing is within a `success` block, so I assume that the web service call was successful, the JSON was unmarshalled, and the objects were persisted in Core Data.  Are there any other checks that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

My best answer without knowing all the details of how you have set up your view controller, is that this issue commonly occurred for me when I had.

A. Inserted a Table View into a View Controller

B. Saving data in the same View Controller.

Regardless of my circumstances, if you are going to save data in a view that also has a Table View you need to remove the following methods which are in your code:

```
- (void) controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

AND

```
-(void) controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
```

The error that occurs is because the fetched results suddenly has changes that the table view is not yet able to recognise ie. "`no object at index 3 in section at index 0`".

If you want to have the table respond to the changes you need to add a `refresh` method and call it after the data has been saved (sounds obvious but Stack Exchange has it's share of people who don't understand that) ie. `[self refresh];` So in your `-(IBAction *) save: (id) sender` method (or void method if you're using that to save), call it from within there.

Hope this helps anyone in future.